# Trying to connect EC-2 instance (Bitnami Wordpress) with Filezilla

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssh

Been trying unsuccessfully to connect to EC-2 on AWS instance through Filezilla. Here is a screenshot of the settings I have on Filezilla Site manager [image]

Here is the error log from Filezilla with the debug log set to 4

```
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(64)
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Connecting to ec2-54-251-155-167.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com...
Trace:          Going to execute /Users/zaidhumayun/Documents/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS/fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp started, protocol_version=6)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
Command:    keyfile "/Users/zaidhumayun/Desktop/FirstInstance.pem"
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend()
Command:    open "ubuntu@ec2-54-251-155-167.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" 22
Trace:          Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
Trace:          We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Trace:          Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:          Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:          Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-dss/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:          Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:          ssh-ed25519 256 7e:1c:94:69:78:c9:13:a3:38:0d:07:54:e9:28:5b:3b
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Trace:          Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Trace:          Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:          Offered public key from "/Users/zaidhumayun/Desktop/FirstInstance.pem"
Trace:          Server refused our key
Trace:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I have no idea why its not accepting my key pair instance. What do I need to do to fix this? Is there some way to re-download the key pair instance? Because according to the amazon documentation, you're allowed to download it once at instance launch.

Comment: In the EC2 management console, does the Keypair name (FirstInstance) match the key you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/cloud/aws), username should be 'bitnami', not 'ubuntu'